# How do we simulate Nuclear explosion?

Tags: soft-question, simulations

I am interested in PC simulation, i use physics equations to simulate rain, fire, wind, cloud and lightning. it is a kind of VR (virtual reality).
what equation is able to simulate a virtual nuclear explosion?
is nuclear explosion continuum?

Comment: This is _PHYSICS_ stack exchange and your question is not appropriate for such a forum.

Comment: what aspect of Nuclear explosion do you want to simulate?

Comment: Please modify your question and ask what aspect of physics would you like to know. What is the model you are working with? What attempts have been made etc.?

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad question, just needs to be clarified a bit. Are you trying to simulate the look of the explosion, the force resulting from the explosion, hydrodynamics of the surrounding atmosphere (and how far away are we talking?)? If you can clarify further I am sure somebody might be able to help you.

Comment: Out FAQ actually list *"Some kinds of questions should not be asked here [...] Computational questions
If your question is about writing a simulation or other program, and it concerns the algorithms, execution, or presentation of the results (rather than the underlying physics), it is probably more appropriate at [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)."* That said, this topic is too big for a single question on any Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 2):

For the simulation of nuclear explosion, there are at least three sets of equations that should be used together:

- Nuclear reactions themselves, collisions and decays, at some given temperature, penetrating fast particles, and abundance of particular nuclei and slow particles, to get the rate of all changes to those numbers, and the energy effect. Maybe the out-of-equilibrium distributions would turn out to be necessary.
- Processes of propagation of particles (including light) through the media. Slowering, scattering, changing the media state.
- Process of shock wave propagation. In the volume of nuclear fuel, the shock wave would be a detonating one, while outside it would be just dissipating the energy.

I do not consider anything aside from the nuclear part itself, i. e. parts of detonator.

These equations fall into three kinds:

- quantum mechanical calculations, with some use of kinematics and experimental measurements;
- kinetics, that is microscopic content of media and its changes with motions and reactions of particles;
- continuum mechanics in the case of the shock wave and the supersonic motion.

Usually it takes a supercomputer to carry out all such simulations. I don't know if a PC is able to perform even the most simplified case.